# passing argument 3 of 'function name' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

So i have an assignment for the university where the user types the prices of some products from a set number of categories he provides and I must find the maximum amount of money he can spend. I also need to use a function for the calculations. I typed the code below and it showed me 2 warnings:

```
line 21 [Warning] passing argument 3 of 'shop' makes pointer from integer without a cast,
line 21 [Warning] passing argument 4 of 'shop' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

and 2 notes:

```
line 4 [Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int', 
line 4 [Note] expected 'int (*)[10]' but argument is of type 'int'
```

The code is this one, it is worth mentioning that we were asked to use a header file to combine the main programm with the function instead of writing all in one page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shoprec.h"

int shop(int m, int n, int K[n], int C[n][10]);

int main(){
    int m, n, i, j,  R;
    printf("please type the maximum amount of money you want to spend \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("please type how many kinds of products you want to buy (like pc, printers. scanners etc.) \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int K[n],C[n][10];
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
        printf("please type the amount of available products for category number %d \n", i);
        scanf("%d", &K[i]);
            for (j=1; j<=K[i]; j++){
            printf("please type the cost of product number %d from category number %d \n", j, i);
            scanf("%d", &C[i][j]);
        }
    }
    R= shop(m, n, K[n], C[n][10]);
    printf ("Maximum amount spent is : %d \n",R)
}
```

The header file is this one:

```
int shop(int m, int n, int K[n], int C[n][10]);
```

And the function code is:

```
int shop(int m, int n, int K[n], int C[n][10]){
    int P,i,j,R;
    P=m;
    R=0;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for (j=1;j<=K[i];j++){
            P=P-C[i][j];
        }
        if (P>R) R=P;
    }
    return R;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Change `R= shop(m, n, K[n], C[n][10]);` to `R= shop(m, n, K, C);`

When you put the `K[n]` you are passing an `int`, not an `int array`as specified by the function signature.